# Recuperar Endereço do Google Maps informando Long e Lat

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tenho as latitude e longitude de uma localização no Google Maps, obtidas a partir de um `marker` e uma função própria, gostaria de saber se alguém tem uma ideia ou função que me retorne o endereço completo do local com base nestes dois parâmetros.

Comment: O que é para ti um "Endereço Completo"? A morada postal correspondente a esse endereço? A hiperligação para a página do Google Maps? Outra coisa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize a URL a seguir para obter um JSON com o endereço:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true
```

Nesse caso, a latitude é: 44.4647452 e a longitude: 7.3553838

Um exemplo, fornecido pelo autor da perguta é mostrado abaixo:

```
var latlng = lat + "," +lng; 
var url = "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=true"; 
$.getJSON(url, function (data) { 
    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) 
    { 
        var adress = data.results[i].formatted_address; 
        //alert(adress); 
        document.getElementById('endereco_saida_maps').value = adress; 
        endereco_campo.value = adress; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Consegui usando a url que informou e criando a função: 
   var latlng = lat + "," +lng;
   var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=true";
   $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
     var adress = data.results[i].formatted_address;
     //alert(adress);
     document.getElementById('endereco_saida_maps').value = adress;
     endereco_campo.value = adress;
    }
   });`

Comment: Outra forma é usar a própria API JS para fazer isto, basta verificar [*reverse geocoding*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra ideia:

```
function cityByLatLng(latitude, longitude) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                document.getElementById('seu elemento').value = results[0].formatted_address;
            } else {
                window.alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```